# Error al implemetar un .jar de Look And Feel

Tags: java, netbeans, look-and-feel

Descargué el *.jar* de **Synthetica**, junto con el *.jar* de **syntheticaDarkLookAndFeel**, ya los añadí a las librerías de mi proyecto y están siento importadas también.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaBlackMoonLookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
```

En el método *main* estoy implementando el siguiente código:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("de.javasoft.synthetica.dark.SyntheticaDarkLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Mapa().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Si opto por un *Clean and Build* realiza el build sin problemas, pero al momento de ejecutar el programa, no se aplica ningún cambio en la parte gráfica. Sigue mostrándose el *NimbusLookAndFeel*

He intentado de la siguiente forma también:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaBlackMoonLookAndFeel());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Mapa().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Pero obtengo una excepción en la línea de `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaBlackMoonLookAndFeel());`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo implementarla correctamente?

Comment: Hola. Recuerda que al preguntar debes añadir la traza de error completa.

Comment: Listo, añadí una imagen del error.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de proyecto es?¿Cómo estás agregando el jar a tu classpath?

Comment: Por qué varias veces la misma pregunta? Por favor, borra una

Comment: ClassNotFound significa que no está encontrando la clase SynthUI. Debes revisar las dependencias (las librerías que estás añadiendo) y que se estén incluyendo en el classpath

Comment: @RuslanLópez Es una Java Application con Forms. Estoy añadiéndolas desde la carpeta _Libraries_  del proyecto.

Comment: ¿ya probaste desactivando la opción compile on save y corriendo el jar generado desde consola?

Comment: @Alfabravo Intenté accediendo directamente a la ruta de la .class y también importándola, pero no me funcionó ningún método.

Comment: Por favor, indica qué versión de Synthetica estás intentando usar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisando el error con un poquito más de detalle, creo que es necesario que revises la librería que intentas usar. El error está diciendo que alguien está intentando usar `sun.swing.plaf.xxxxx` y eso no lo estás importando directamente.

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html), para Java8 el paquete es `javax.swing.plaf.synth`. El acceso directo a sun.xyz se desaconseja porque no refiere a la API disponible y te va a fallar si usas algo diferente a Oracle Java o si cambias de versión y la implementación cambia.

Veo que Synthetica tiene versiones diferentes para Java <=8 y Java>9. Revísalo. Así mismo, confirma qué versión de Java estás usando.

Comment: Tienes razón. Estaba intentando añadir un LookAndFeel de Synthetica disponible para Java 9.